# intellisense in Eclipse for currently saved files does not get reflected

Tags: android, eclipse, intellisense

i am developing android project which was working fine but at the middle somehow i am not able to add my newly created XML layout files to my Java files as it does not show me option when i write "SetContentView(R.Layout.)",please if some one have any solution plz suggest them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for some times to load.

Simply try `refresh` your project Or goto `Project->Clean` and `Build` your project. I think it's the problem with eclipse automatic building.

Comment: i restart my eclipse as well as my system several times but no result

Answer (score 0):

After creating a layout Clean your Project to initialize Xml pointers

```
on Menu bar -> Project -> Clean
```

Answer (score 0):

some time problem in resource folder in your project, just delete the such a bugs and clean and build the project it will work.